# rsRenderingExtensionNotFound error using SSRS 2005

Tags: rendering, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to use the [Sharp-shooter Silverlight report viewer](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Report-Sharp-Shooter-for-Silverlight.aspx) control.

This control has a server side component that renders the reports as XAML for displaying in the client side control. I have tried manually installing the rendering extension, according to the [instructions](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Product.aspx?lang=en&pid=116&tid=gettingstarted) on their website, and also the [instructions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154516.aspx).

I have basically copied the dll's into the reporting services bin folder and added the following line to rsreportserver.config file:

```
<Extension Name="XAML" Type="PerpetuumSoft.ReportingService.XamlRendering.XamlRenderer,PerpetuumSoft.ReportingService.XamlRendering"/>
```

I've also added a line into the rssrvpolicy.config file as specified on their site.

After I made these changes I went into windows services and restarted the Reporting Services services but I get the following error when I try to run reports:

> rsRenderingExtensionNotFound: An
>   attempt has been made to use a
>   rendering extension that is not
>   registered for this report server

Is there anything else that I need to do to use a custom rendering extension within SSRS 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with the dll, after much to-ing and fro-ing with the guys at Perpetuum software they figured out the bug and put out another release.